# Unable to change image of button in UItableViewCell on click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UITableView with multiple cells, and in each cell is a button. The button in the first cell is green, whilst the rest are grey. I want to set it such that if the user taps any of the grey buttons, the button in the first cell becomes grey, and the tapped button becomes green.

```
@IBOutlet weak var answeredTick: UIButton!
cell.answeredTick.tag = indexPath.row


@IBAction func answerTickPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    guard let answeredTick = sender as? UIButton else { return }

    if let buttonToMakeGrey = answeredTick.viewWithTag(0) as? UIButton {
        buttonToMakeGrey.setImage(UIImage(named: "greyTick.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
        print("no success")
    }

    if let buttonToMakeGrey = answeredTick.viewWithTag(answeredTick.tag) as? UIButton {
        buttonToMakeGrey.setImage(UIImage(named: "greenTick.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
        print("no success 1")
    }
}
```

The above always fails to change the green tick to grey, and prints 'no success'. Why is this and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think answeredThick does not have view with Tag 0.

For example: You click 3rd row button and "guard let answeredTick" variable only has tag for "2" view. It does not have first cell's answeredTick instance.

You can access first cell via cellForRowAtIndexPath and then change color. However you should be careful for dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier cells, you can see green buttons more than one.

Easy way to do it : You can hold array for cells. When you press button or cell you can change neccessary variables with array and reload tableView.